# The connection to the server 172.31.58.39:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeadm, ubuntu-22.04, aws-ec2

I have created 3 nodes on aws ec2. In these three nodes, I have one master node with type t2.medium and 2 worker nodes with type t2.micro

I'm facing an issue `The connection to the server 172.31.58.39:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` for the last 2 days and I'm unable to resolve this issue. I have searched all things related to this issue but no one solution did not work.

```
EC2: t2.medium
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
kubeadm version: 
        &version.Info{Major:"1", 
                      Minor:"28", 
                      GitVersion:"v1.28.2", 
                 
                GitCommit:"89a4ea3e1e4ddd7f7572286090359983e0387b2f", 
              GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-09-13T09:34:32Z", 
                GoVersion:"go1.20.8", 
                  Compiler:"gc", 
                  Platform:"linux/amd64"}

kubectl version:
              Client Version: v1.28.2
              Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
```

`kubectl get nodes`

```
E0923 17:25:20.923628    7300 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.31.58.39:6443/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")
E0923 17:25:20.928061    7300 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.31.58.39:6443/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")
E0923 17:25:20.932249    7300 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.31.58.39:6443/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")
E0923 17:25:20.936440    7300 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.31.58.39:6443/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")
E0923 17:25:20.940482    7300 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.31.58.39:6443/api?timeout=32s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "Kubernetes")
Unable to connect to the server: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "Kubernetes")
```

Some get this error on
`kubectl get nodes`

```
Unable to connect to the server: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")
```

and some time get this error on
`kubectl get nodes`

```
The connection to the server 172.31.58.39:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

`kubectl cluster-info`

```
E0924 07:51:01.606793   10760 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.31.58.39:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 172.31.58.39:6443: connect: connection refused
E0924 07:51:01.607243   10760 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.31.58.39:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 172.31.58.39:6443: connect: connection refused
E0924 07:51:01.608930   10760 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.31.58.39:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 172.31.58.39:6443: connect: connection refused
E0924 07:51:01.610408   10760 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.31.58.39:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 172.31.58.39:6443: connect: connection refused
E0924 07:51:01.611920   10760 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://172.31.58.39:6443/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp 172.31.58.39:6443: connect: connection refused

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server 172.31.58.39:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

`.kube/config`

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0F----
    server: https://172.31.58.39:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJ----
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJ---
```

`netstat -pnlt | grep 6443`

```
Got nothing

some time get this response from above command
tcp6       1      0 :::6443                 :::*                    LISTEN      89485/kube-apiserve
```

`firewall-cmd --list-all`

```
You're performing an operation over default zone ('public'),
but your connections/interfaces are in zone 'docker' (see --get-active-zones)
You most likely need to use --zone=docker option.

public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Master Node Security Group (Inbound)

```
–   sgr-084c44b571f12226d   8080        TCP 0.0.0.0/0   MasterSecurityGroups    –
–   sgr-01784eb1f091d49f9   6430        TCP 0.0.0.0/0   MasterSecurityGroups    –
–   sgr-071619a3b2faa66e6   22          TCP 0.0.0.0/0   MasterSecurityGroups    –
–   sgr-0ef554af49b020d01   6784        UDP 0.0.0.0/0   MasterSecurityGroups    –
–   sgr-0f54b7b5d068e3fc8   6783        TCP 0.0.0.0/0   MasterSecurityGroups    –
–   sgr-05e5c889e6d056897   2379 - 2380 TCP 0.0.0.0/0   MasterSecurityGroups    –
–   sgr-03adee8559fe297ca   6443        TCP 0.0.0.0/0   MasterSecurityGroups    –
–   sgr-0bd29c6cad853563b   443         TCP 0.0.0.0/0   MasterSecurityGroups    –
–   sgr-06a00288ac397903a   80          TCP 0.0.0.0/0   MasterSecurityGroups    –
–   sgr-05eed4b9a8e95625c   30000 - 32767   TCP 0.0.0.0/0   MasterSecurityGroups    –
```

I'm confused about IP about my `EC2` and local ip, let me show you
I have checked
`curl -s ifconfig.me`
then i got

```
54.157.171.165  => This is my master node Public IPv4 address
```

However in `.kube/config` coming from my local IP in the server with port `6443`

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTi====
    server: https://172.31.58.39:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBD====
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1C====
```

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem?

Comment: Dear! It did not work for me. it is a version issue of kubeadm

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this error **Unable to connect to the server: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")**

**Try below steps:**

**1** Check to see if a valid certificate is present in the $HOME/.kube/config file and generate a new certificate.

**2** Remove the environment variable KUBECONFIG by using:

```
unset KUBECONFIG
```

Or set it to the default KUBECONFIG location:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
```

**3** Another workaround is to replace the existing kubeconfig for the “admin” user:

```
mv  $HOME/.kube $HOME/.kube.bak mkdir $HOME/.kube sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

You need to make sure you are using the correct kubeconfig since reinstalling Kubernetes creates a new certificate.

Either use $HOME/.kube/config in setKubeconfig option or just copy it to path where you have set vs code extension to read the config from. Using following command

```
cp $HOME/.kube/config /{{path-for-kubeconfig}}
```

To resolve this error **The connection to the server 172.31.58.39:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?**

**Try to do below steps on master node  to resolve your issue**

1. sudo -i
2. swapoff -a
3. exit
4. strace -eopenat kubectl version

Restarting your container with sudo systemctl restart containerd is another recommendation.

Comment: Can you explain the rationale on doing `swapoff -a` (which gets less overall memory available to the system) to resolve a network connection error? If you suggest doing it, you can certainly explain why it should be done, can't you?

Comment: I have done all the steps but  after some time, again I'm facing same issue so i found the issue why is coming because of version issue of kubeadm